# Why React Native TextInput doesn't change value when state updating?

Tags: react-native

I need to show in TextInput only first symbol from user input. This is very simple and I'am confusing about why so simple code is not working?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {

            text: '',
        };

        this.handleChangeText = this.handleChangeText.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeText (text) {

        text = text.charAt(0);

        this.setState({
            text: text.toString(),
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (<View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style={{width: 100, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000',}} value={this.state.text} onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}/>
        </View>);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 suggestions. 1. start with a different initial value, maybe it's not showing due to style issues. 2. reassigning `text` on you function may not work nice, try `this.setState({ text: text.charAt(0).toString() })` instead

Comment: @nirsky Unfortunately both doesn't decide a problem

Comment: Its an issue in react-native, check out this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18874. I will check if I can find any workaround.

Comment: @RaviRaj I'am already see information about issue, but can't find a decision :) It is an important bug, why facebook command can't fix it several React Native versions?